# Left Outer Join on ModelCluster ParentalManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django-models, left-join, django-orm, wagtail

Given the following models:

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalManyToManyField

@register_snippet
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class BlogPost(Page):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogCategory', blank=True)
    ...
```

Using `Django ORM`, how can I achieve the same output as with the following `SQL Join`:

```
SELECT bc.name, count(bp.id) posts
FROM BlogCategory bc LEFT JOIN BlogPost bp
ON bc.id=bp.category
GROUP BY bc.id;
 name | posts 
------+-------
 cat3 |     0
 cat2 |     2
 cat1 |     1
(3 rows)
```

I'm just trying to get a list of categories with the number of posts in each category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

BlogCategory.objects.annotate(
    posts=Count('blogpost')
)
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` containing `BlogCategory`s, where every `BlogCategory` has an extra attribute: `posts` that contains the number of posts for *that* category.

Or if you are only interested in a `QuerySet` of dictionaries:

```
from django.db.models import Count

BlogCategory.objects.values('id', 'name').annotate(
    num_posts=Count('blogpost')
).order_by('id', 'name')
```

This will result in a `QuerySet` like:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 3, 'name': 'cat3', 'posts': 0},
           {'id': 2, 'name': 'cat2', 'posts': 2},
           {'id': 1, 'name': 'cat1', 'posts': 1}]>
```